# Laravel 'like' query with MongoDB connection

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5, eloquent

I am facing an issue in laravel 'like' query. I have a MIS on laravel with databases on MongoDb. Now my DB has a table named `kw` with urlencoded keywords like `cars%20in%20London`, Now my query gives accurate results for `cars` or `cars%20in%20London` but when I search `cars%20in` I get 0 results! This is how laravel 'like' is used in query but Mongo uses /.*m*./ form, How can I make this working. Here is my Model function

---

```
public static function selectKeywordIncomplete($keyword) {   
    $search_volume_incomplete = searchVolume::where('kw','like','%'.$keyword.'%')->orwhere('kw','=',$keyword)->where('status','=',1)->paginate(20);
    return $search_volume_incomplete; 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using regex like `$search_volume_incomplete = searchVolume::where('kw','regex', new MongoRegex("/^$keyword/i"))->orwhere('kw','=',$keyword)->where('status','=',1)->paginate(20);`?

Comment: Don't know whether it works but Class 'App\Models\MongoRegex' not found , this is the error coming, well jessengers is already included, i am looking in the issue but if you know then lemme know , thanks.

Answer (score 1):

well as there is no such thing as 'like' in mongoDb, I looked for Mongodb regex, but laravel regexp for mongoDB worked as a charm,
here is the query which worked.
http://jenssegers.be/projects/laravel-mongodb

> $search_volume_unprocessed =
>   searchVolume::where('kw','=',$keyword)->orwhere('kw','regexp',"/.*$keyword/i")->where('status','=',1)->paginate(20);